# Is there a CLT-type result for $S^2$?

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

The subject line is essentially the question: it there a theorem, like the CLT for the sample average, that allows us to say anything useful about the distribution of the sample variance as the sample size increases? I've seen simulations of the distribution of $S^2$ from distributions with high and low kurtosis as the sample sizes increase and they do appear to converge on the normal distribution. But I don't recall a theorem to that effect. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Just normalize to mean zero then apply CLT to the square of the random variable.

Comment: Really, it's that simple?? I there a theorem to that effect?

Comment: It's just a direct application of the CLT. There's no need for a separate theorem, it's the same theorem.

Comment: If you put this in the form of an answers I'll check it and close this out.